# OAuth2 Login (Not Authorization)

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have implemented an OAuth2 register workflow (in Java) according to [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

I'm using GitLab as OAuth2 Provider.

After the user granted access to my application for his account, I get an OAuth Token (along with refresh token and other stuff), I am able to make API requests on behalf of the user, so this is working fine.

This way I can get the users e-mail adress which I use to create an internal user.

My questions are:

1. Is it practice to issue a token that is generated by my application for the user (along with the OAuthToken) or should I just use the token that has been issued by the OAauth Provider? (My App also has local auth with bearer tokens). This token will be used for further API - CLIENT communication (stored in Angular2 local storage as bearer)
2. How to do login only? When a OAuth User accesses my web service, how do I know that this user is a OAuth User and which OAuth Token belongs to him? How can the user login without providing e-mail or password? (The user has no password) I guess I have to redirect him to the OAuth Provider again, but I don't want my user to grant access everytime he logs in.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:**

Though you can use the token provided by OAuth provider, you **SHOULD NOT** use it considering the risk that may arise exposing it to the public.

Instead you should securely save the token provided by OAuth provider into the database and use another token for authentication of further api calls. (you could use [**JWT**](https://jwt.io/))

**Answer 2:**

There are two types of systems

1. Which always uses OAuth provider for identifying user. (Ex. [Tinder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tinder&hl=en))
2. Which provides both OAuth Login and Traditional login/signup. (Ex. [Quora](https://www.quora.com/), [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/))

If you want your application to follow 2nd approach, you should ask the user to create password for the first time when the user logs in using OAuth provider.

This will allow the user to log into your application by both methods, traditional as well as OAuth

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: My question is how to log the user in without username and password, like the Facebook or Google Log in Button on a lot of sites.

Answer (score 1):

1. To identify users of your application, you should either use HTTP session or issue your own tokens. Do not use tokens generated by the OAuth2 provider - they are meant to be used just by your backend (in role of an OAuth2 client).
2. To use an external authentication in your application, you probably want to use OpenID Connect, not a bare OAuth2. OpenID Connect extends OAuth2 and it's meant for authentication instead of the rights delegation. Then you use an implicit flow (instead of authentication code grant) with scope=openid, your frontend app (HTML+JavaScript) gets an ID token signed by the OAuth2 provider. After successful signature verification, your backend can trust that the client is the one described in the ID token (in its "sub" field). Then you can either keep using the ID token or generate your own token.